# $dX_t=\alpha X_t \,dt + \sqrt{X_t} \,dW_t, $ with $X_0=x_0,\,\alpha,\sigma>0.$ Compute $E[X_t] $ and $E[Y]$ for $Y=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-\alpha t}X_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

First of all i suppose that there is no easy analytical solution to the SDE? I got the hint to use Gronwall to show that there is a constant $C$ , s.t. $E[X_{t\land\tau_n}]\le C$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, with $\tau_n=\inf(t\ge0: |X_t|\ge n)\land n.$

It is unclear to me how the hint is helping. If I could show it, I still would only have an upper bound for $E[X_t]$.

I think Y will have expectation $x_0$, since the drift gets eliminated but I don`t know how to prove the existence of Y and my guess.

Edit: $\alpha$ and $ \sigma$ are constants

Comment: What is $\alpha$, a constant, a time dependent only function?

Comment: It is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for the moment being that we already **know** that $$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} \mathbb{E}(|X_t|) \leq C < \infty \tag{1}$$ for any $T>0$. Follow the following steps to solve the problem:

1. Recall the following statement: If $f$ is a progressively mapping such that $\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^T f(s)^2 \, ds \right)<\infty$ for any $T>0$, then $$M_t := \int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$$ is a martingale; in particular $$\mathbb{E}(M_t)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)=0.$$
2. Use Step 1 and Fubini's theorem to show that $$\mathbb{E}(X_t)-x_0 =\alpha \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(X_s) \, ds. \tag{2}$$
3. By $(2)$, the mapping $u(t) := \mathbb{E}(X_t)$ solves the ordinary differential equation $$\frac{d}{dt} u(t) = \alpha u(t), \qquad u(0)=x_0.$$ Solve it.
4. Apply Itô's formula to show that $$e^{-\alpha t} X_t - x_0 = \int_0^t e^{-\alpha s} \sqrt{X_s} \, W_s.$$
5. Conclude that $$Y=\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-\alpha t} X_t$$ almost surely and in $L^1$. (Hint: Show that $e^{-\alpha t}X_t$ is an $L^2$-bounded martingale.)
6. Because of the $L^1$-convergence, it follows from Step 4 that $$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(e^{-\alpha t} X_t) = x_0.$$

It remains to prove $(1)$:

1. Show that the process $$M_t^{(n)} := \int_0^{t \wedge \tau_n} \sqrt{X_s} \, dW_s$$ is a martingale for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$; here $$\tau_n := \inf\{t \geq 0; |X_t| \geq n\} \wedge n.$$ In particular, $M_t^{(n)}$ has expectation zero.
2. Use Itô's formula and step 1 to show that $$\mathbb{E}(X_{t \wedge \tau_n})-x_0 = \alpha \mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^{t \wedge \tau_n} X_s \, ds \right) \leq \alpha \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(X_{s \wedge \tau_n}) \, ds.$$
3. Apply the Gronwall lemma to prove that there exists a constant $C=C(T,x_0)>0$ such that $$\sup_{t \leq T} \mathbb{E}(X_{t \wedge \tau_n}) \leq C \qquad \text{for all $n \geq 1$}.$$ Use Fatous lemma to conclude that $$\sup_{t \leq T} \mathbb{E} \left(  X_t \right) \leq C.$$

Comment: I think you forgot the $\sigma$ in $\int_0^t \sigma e^{- \alpha s} \sqrt{X_s} dW_s$. Just one more thing: Do you know if there is a closed form solution to the SDE? Seems similar to the CIR Model SDE with out of bound parameters.

Comment: @Andrew There is no $\sigma$ in the definition of $X_t$. And no, I'm not aware of a closed form for the solution.

Comment: Oops I made a type in the exercise it should be $\sigma \sqrt{X_t} dW_t, with $\sigma>0$. But that doesn't change the correctness of your solution of course.

Comment: With the same rigor you demanded of my answer, it is not that simple. You need to show the existence of the solution before even your first step.

Comment: @Hans The same rigor? This must be a joke. I answered the OPs question. He wasn't asking for a proof of the existence of a solution to the SDE.

Comment: Does your integrand $\sqrt{X_s}$ mean anything if the solution to the SDE does not exist?

Comment: @Hans Just replace $\sqrt{X_s}$ by $\sqrt{|X_s|}$ and the calculations remain valid. As I said: The OP wasn't asking about the existence of the solution to the SDE, and therefore I take it that (s)he knows that a solution exists. It is not my job to answer all questions the OP might or might not have. If he had asked about the existence, I would have written something about that as well -but he didn't. (... and if you think that you can write a better answer, then just go ahead.)

Comment: The non-negativity of $X_t$ needs to be proven which is not hard. Before that, the existence should be proved. The latter is not trivial, since the usual global Lipschitz condition does not apply as the solution $X_t$ if exists, actually hits $0$ with positive probability. You can also say the OP could just assume $\sup_{t \in [0,T]} \mathbf E(|X_t|) \leq C < \infty \tag{1}$ for any $T>0$. All that Gronwall business is then a moot question.

Comment: @Hans How could I assume that if the OP mentions explicitly in his question that he was told to prove the $L^1$-boundedness? If you want to write a more detailed answer to the question, then please go ahead; you're most welcome. If you are just annoyed because I downvoted your answer, then you can either improve your answer or remove it.

Comment: Does $L_1$ boundedness of $X_t$ not predicate on the existence of $X_t$? Regarding the downvote, I am not as presumptuous. I try to be fair and would have a discussion with the solver to give him a chance to defend himself before I downvote. That said, I want to stress that there is no disrespect as I on the contrary highly respect your skill and knowledge. I just try to be fair and objective.

Comment: Actually the proof of nonnegativity of $X_t$ goes hand in hand with that of the existence of the solution. So the square root itself does not even make sense without the previous two properties, which is the very premise of $L_1$ boundedness. Without the existence, all the subsequent steps are vacuous.

Comment: @Hans I don't get your point. The OP didn't include much information on his background, and therefore I just answered the questions he was asking. If he has any further questions, then he is welcome to ask them. This seems fair enough to me. You might have noticed that the OP already accepted the answer, and therefore it seems that he was satisfied with it.

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify what kind of function $\alpha$ is. Assume it is a constant. Take expectation of the SDE, as $\mathbf E[dW_t]=0$, 
$$dx = \alpha xdt \Longleftrightarrow x(t)=x(0)e^{\alpha t}\Longleftrightarrow y(t)=e^{-\alpha t}x(t)=x(0),$$
where $x(t):=\mathbf E[X_t]$ and $y(t):=\mathbf E[e^{-\alpha t}X_t]$.

---

I will add the existence of $\mathbf E[X_t]$ later, but soon.

Comment: It's not that simple... for instance you first have to show that $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ actually exists (i.e. that $\mathbb{E}(|X_t|)$ is finite). Moreover, $x(t) \neq x(0) e^{\alpha t}$. (We have $\mathbb{E}(X_t) = x_0 e^{\alpha t}$, but $X(t)$ is a random process and does not equal its expectation.)

Comment: @saz: I know. I just want to put out the general direction for solving the problem. Also in my haste, I forgot to define $x(t):=\mathbf E[X_t]$, which I added just now. Does that answer the "Moreover" part of your objection?

Comment: @saz: Would you mind rescinding the downvote for now, to give me time to add the necessary details? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, for the moment I don't intend to rescind the downvote. Your answer is not helpful. Just ping me when you have edited your answer and I'll consider rescinding my downvote.

Comment: @saz: Fair enough. But could you please answer my previous question?

Comment: Yes, it does...